# Getting 500 internal server error in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to run the google.com in jmeter
I have add the thread and the http request and try to run then display error

I have add the thread and the http request and try to run then display error
want solution of the error

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the same requests as your browser does in order to get the same responses.

Opening google search page should be as simple as:

[image]

and performing a search is something like:

[image]

End to end demo:

[image]

If you're uncertain regarding how to properly configure JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), etc. you can just record your test scenario using a web browser and JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)

Comment: Not working in my pc.still display error